# Pass variable and form.serialise array to controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to pass form data to controller, that can be done easily,
But i along with form.serialise array, i want to pass one additional variable value as well,

I tried with below code,
I could able to print ID value in console.log but when form data send to controller, ID is pass as string id, not number,

How can i pass variable value?

```
  event.preventDefault();
            var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
            var id = pathArray[6];
            console.log(id);

            $("#LoadingImage").show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/expensecenter/add_expense",
                    data: $("#expense_common").serialize() + "&report_id=id",
```

I want to pass value 13(this is number in url) to as report_id, how can i do that?

Comment: try parse variable into number like parseInt(pathArray[6]); or &report_id="+parseInt(id), ... And the placing of id variable in data is wrong. Should be $report_id="+id,.

Comment: Glad it worked..!.Then please accept my answer, others people can refer that later on.

Comment: I wish i could, but my reputation point is still low, so saying not allowed to vote ;-(

Comment: Accepting answer not rely on reputation i think because only the owner of posted can accepting answer. Not voting but accepting answer. "The right symbols on my answer below". If still can't, nevermind. Glad your problem solved :)

Comment: Oh yes, i see now, i was clicking on UP arrow :-) Its done now.

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to pass array+variable? I tried this for passing array+id, but this not worked,   var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
  var id = pathArray[6];
  
  var expense = new Array();
  $('input[name="select_expense"]:checked').each(function() {
  expense.push(this.value);
         }); 
         console.log(expense);
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/expensecenter/trash_expense",
       data: {expense:expense} + "&report_id="+parseInt(id),
       type: "POST",

Comment: You better post your question on new thread. We will catch up you there. And of course high chance to get the answer.

Comment: Not allowing me to add new question till next 7 days :-(

Comment: what you got from the code?

Comment: When i post my ajax request, i get this [object Object]:
report_id:17, earlier i used to get expense[]:105 report_id:17. without adding "&report_id="+parseInt(id),  In short i need to pass jquery array object + one variable.

Comment: Did you ever try to put report_id variable together like this.. data : {expense:expense, report_id : parseInt(id) }. And at the server side you just get the data using $this->input->post('expense'); and $this->input->post('report_id');

Comment: You are great my Dear friend, thank you so much for wonderful support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure sending the `integer value`, use this:

```
data: $("#expense_common").serialize() + "&report_id=" + parseInt(id),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data: $("#expense_common").serialize() + "&report_id=" + id,
```